# std::promise not emit unused warning

Tags: c++, c++11, promise

```
#include <upstream>
#include <future>

void test() {
    std::promise<int> m;
     int a;
}
int main(){
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

g++-5.4.0 —std=c++11 Wall test.cpp -o myexpect

however, a will emit a unused variable warning, m does not?
is this compiler a bug?

Comment: `a` is an `int`, so its construction and destruction carries no side effects. `m` is a `std::promise<int>`, which has both nontrivial constructors and destructors. The act of building and tearing down the variable itself carries real effects in your program.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Then, how do we understand *unused-variable* ?

Comment: I know how *I* understand *unused variable*, but that is probably a bit different from what the compiler regards as unused. The compiler has to make conservative decisions in the face of potential side-effects, because it can not read my mind.

Comment: @j6t talk is cheap，show me code :)